# SSIS Foreach Loop Container enumerator did not find any files while deployed on SQL server

Tags: ssis, windows-authentication, foreach-loop-container, folder-permissions

I have created a SSIS package that imports CSV files from a folder and writes data into a database. I can run the package locally but when deployed to SQL server and trying to run it via Execute command. The Foreach Loop Container gives a warning as shown in the pic below. 
[image]

I am currently using a login that is present on the Security\Logins list in SQL server as shown in the pic below: [image]

I have given the user permission to the folder containing the files like show here below [image].

But I still get error while running the package. Can anyone give me clues that might lead to a solution?

Comment: The files are in the same folder on the SQL Server as they are on your local box?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same folder.

Comment: Can you show us the files on the Database server, and the filters on your foreach enumerator?